# .ToArray() changes the dimension of my array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

In my `C#` program I've created an array of string:

```
var arrayTest = new string[20];
```

I need to copy in it some string that I retrive from a `List` containing 10 strings.

```
arrayTest = listTest.ToArray();
```

This works but `.ToArray()` changes the dimension of my array based on the number of element in the list.

I need to maintain the same size (20) and have the 10 strings and the 10 null (or whatever value..)

Is there a way to accomplish this other than loop `listTest` ?

Comment: Calling `arrayTest = listTest.ToArray()` doesn't change the dimension of the original array. It is completely creating a new one. If you maintain a reference to the original array you'll see that it still has 20 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btfeahds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [List<T>.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/t69dktcd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// You can copy either 'List<T>' or 'Array' by using this
Array.Copy(listTest.ToArray(), arrayTest, listTest.Length);
```

or the method below inspired by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498)

```
// You can copy 'List<T>' by using this, but it doesn't require a 'ToArray()' function
// It's better to use this if you're copying with 'List<T>'
listTest.CopyTo(arrayTest)
```

Using the above codes copies the `listText`'s content to `arrayTest`, and it doesn't modify the rest of the values inside `arrayTest`.

But should make sure the size of `arrayTest` is longer or same as `listTest`'s length, otherwise it'll throw an exception.

**Why your code didn't work**

The original code you have:

```
arrayTest = listTest.ToArray();
```

This makes the `arrayTest` points to a whole new reference, so the size `20` doesn't make any sense, since the array with length `20` will be garbage collected afterwards. Changing `20` to different sizes still results the same.

Comment: You have linked a chinese version of msdn

Comment: This is plagiarism... It was Damien_The_Unbeliever, who posted the best answer. Already a meta post was viral about this stuff : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319644/summing-up-answers-in-the-top-answer

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I've seen the link you posted, so what should I do? Delete the four lines with Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer?

Comment: I posted the answer with a feasible solution and why the codes which the OP uses don't work.And then I saw a better approach, so I listed the solution owner and added it as a substitution.

Comment: I don't think this is a sum up solution, since it only takes up 20% of my full answer.

Comment: @J3soon What's done is done, I don't think that the OP is going to visit this again, too soon. Since yours is the accepted answer, keep that solution in it as well, don't delete it, but in future try avoiding it :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your list is generic, you can just use its [`List<T>.CopyTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69dktcd(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
listTest.CopyTo(arrayTest);
```

Rather than the other answers which create another array just to copy from it and then throw it away.

Even for non-generic lists, there are `Copy` methods on most such classes that, again, allow you to copy the data directly into a target array, rather than calling `ToArray` first.

Comment: I didn't know that all collections had that method. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Array.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Array.Copy(listTest.ToArray(), 0, arrayTest, 0, listTest.Count);
```

This will not change the size of the array to which you are copying.

[Here's](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-copy) a good article on the above method. It is very useful.

Also, take a look at this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eDcfuT). I have explained all the code there.